# ASP.NET Core MVC Routing to Controller not working after name clash

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I originally had 2 controllers with the same name "AgreementController" but one was in an "API" namespace.  This caused errors with the routing, using the settings below:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

In order to solve this I renamed the one in the "API" namespace to "AgreementAPIController", but for some reason I still can't route to "/Agreement/Create/?customerId=1234" even though the controllers looks like this:

```
public class AgreementController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;


    public AgreementController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create(int customerId)
    {
        return View(customerId);
    }        
}
```

and

```
public class AgreementAPIController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AgreementAPIController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If I also rename the "AgreementController" to "AgreementXController" then everything works fine.  How come I have to rename both controllers?  Is there some kind of cache somewhere that is holding onto the old names?

This is the full Startup.cs file.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IRFDbRepository, RFDbRepository>();
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("RFDbConnection");
        services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        services.AddDbContext<RFDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<UserRole>, RoleStore>();
        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddAuthorization(x =>
        {
            if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("DisableAuthentication") && Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                x.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAssertion(_ => true)
                    .Build();
            }
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.AllowAreas = true;
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Configuration.GetValue<int>("AuthenticationCookie:ExpiryMinutes"));
            options.SlidingExpiration = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("AuthenticationCookie:SlidingExpiration");
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IRFDbRepository rFDbRepository)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        loggerFactory.AddFile(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:LogFile"));
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });

        rFDbRepository.TestConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show both controllers.it is probably a naming convention issue. namespace is ignored when mapping routes.

Comment: Also the order of those two routes will conflict as the first one will grab all those intended for the second route. The first is too general. More specific route need to be added before more general routes. I suggest using attribute routing.

Comment: Try `[Route("api/[controller]")]` attribute, above your agreement controller.

Comment: Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I've added the other controller for you to see.

Comment: I agree that I could use attribute routing to resolve this but I don't see why it won't work as it is.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the whole project/solution?

Comment: Just tried that again, didn't help I'm afraid.  All works fine if I use any name apart from AgreementController.

Comment: I tried adding attribute routing the the API controllers and removing the second "MapRoute" shown above.  Still can't hit "/Agreement/Create/?customerId=1234"

Comment: do you by change have an `agreement` folder in the project? You say you cant hit endpoint. what response do you get 404, 400, 500?

Comment: I get a 404 error. The only folder called agreement is "wwwroot/js/Agreement" which is where I keep the javascript for that controller

Comment: Also the "Views/Agreement" folder

Comment: Share us your complete `Startup`.

Comment: I've added the startup file.